# css psuedo class ::before ::after drop shadows not laying over other elements

Tags: html, css

I'm using a css drop shadow technique found here:

http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/

It uses the psuedo classes, before and after, to give more shape to your shadows. The problem is that I can't get the shadow to display over other elements.

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S7dzj/6/

I have tried various relative positioning of the div's with different z-indexes.
I have also tried to move the header element within the *top* div, no help.
I have also tried moving the *top* div relatively `top: -5px` to make it go underneath the *header* div but still no shadow.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The `z-index` property only applies to elements which are not `position: static`, so your `.top` class was merely ignoring that property.
2. Your `.header` and `.top` classes both had the same `z-index`, so the header was appearing on top.

[**See the updated jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/KRG3K/) All I did was add `position: relative` (which doesn't visually do anything on its own) to `.top` and change it's `z-index` to `-2`.

Comment: Quick follow up, what about if I wanted to add a similar shadow to the `top` div, like this http://jsfiddle.net/KRG3K/3/ ? The only way I can get that bottom shadow to show up correctly is to remove the `z-index` of `top` but that obviously hides the first shadow. Any thoughts?

Comment: Updated that fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KRG3K/4/ Any help you could give me would be appreciated.

Comment: @Jakobud: Something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/b4rET/1/)? I basically reversed it to use positive z-indices because dealing with negatives becomes quite a problem when trying to play with multiple elements in a row like that.

Comment: Ah man thanks. That was a tricky one. I was playing with all the z-index values but couldnt get it right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the shadow to overlap `.top`, then see animuson`s answer.

If not, see http://jsfiddle.net/S7dzj/8/

```
.drop-shadow{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

If you add margins, you wil see the shadow.

Comment: The question was *css psuedo class ::before ::after drop shadows not laying **over other elements***, but thanks anyways.

Comment: @Jakobud Haha, you're right, but I don't like it with the shadow laying over the next element... So I wanted to say what I would have done with shadows. And I wanted to post also the solution with the shadow laying over, but animuson was faster than me...